# Python - Group by with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying do gropby function with condition and I am not sure how to get this to work.

Here is how my data looks like:

```
        generated_id    timestamp   direction   date    hour
0   1   1590394859141   forward 2020-05-25 04:20:59.141000-04:00    4
1   2   1599758616945   forward 2020-09-10 13:23:36.945000-04:00    13
2   3   1599759625509   backward    2020-09-10 13:40:25.509000-04:00    13
```

I need to get count of values "forward" direction for each hour. Based on the same data above, I should have one value "forward at 4 and 1 "forward" values for 13.

I am trying to use this:

```
daily_sum = daily_df.groupby("hour")['direction'].count().reset_index()
```

Direction can also be backwards so I only need to focus on forward.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
daily_sum = daily_df[daily_df['direction'] == 'forward']\
             .groupby("hour")['direction'].count().reset_index()
```